# How to Style Textarea with input type submit button

Tags: css

i want to make professional look of button "open urls" and "reset" in the following code but there is no separate CSS i can add in google sites. I have to add the CSS with in the code. here is what i have done so far. please guide me to do the following task.

add "Open Url" and "Reset" button in center on below of "textarea"
add beautiful professional CSS to these buttons.
I am doing this code on [url opener](https://sites.google.com/site/besthiraseo/url-opener) site.

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <br />
    <textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onClick="open_all();">
  <br />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
  <br/>
</form>
<style>
textarea { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
    }

</style>
```

here is java code ..

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      alert("My First Jquery Test");
   });
  function open_all() {
        debugger;
        var urls = document.getElementById("list_urls").value;
        var urls = urls.split('\n');
        var totalno = urls.length;
        var s;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalno; i++) {
            s = urls[i];
            if (s) {
                if (s.substr(0, 7) != 'http://' && s.substr(0, 8) != 'https://')
                    s = 'http://' + s;
                window.open(s);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Open Url` and `Reset` button set in center on below of "textarea". Now add style to make it professional look

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <br />
  <textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="url-button">
      <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onClick="open_all();">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
  </div>
  <br/>
</form>

<style>
    textarea { 
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
        }
    .url-button{
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .url-button input{
        background-color: #2980b9;
        border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
        padding:10px;
        border-radius:5px;
        width:100px;
        color:#fff;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for this help, i have another question related to it, when i use this and click on open urls, chrome block it because of popup, is there any way so chrome should not block it?

Comment: remove $(function(){
      alert("My First Jquery Test");
   }); from code

Comment: still being blocked. :(

Comment: not working. still blocked :) even after removing debugger;

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form method="post" action="">
    <textarea name="list_urls" id="list_urls" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
  <br />
  <div class="action">
    <input value="Open URLs" class="submit" type="button" onClick="open_all();">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset!">
  </div>
</form>
<style>
textarea { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
    }
    
.action {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
input {
  background: lightseagreen;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for this help, i have another question related to it, when i use this and click on open urls, chrome block it because of popup, is there any way so chrome should not block it?

Comment: added into question.

Comment: are you using iframe ?

Comment: this might help you [https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox/](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox/)